# Android: Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm giving maintenance to an old Eclipse Android project that wasn't migrated to Android Studio. Given its complexity, migrating it to Android Studio is not trivial, and the next version of the project is already in Android Studio anyway.

Last time I opened it it worked and built just fine, but this time it shows me this error that doesn't allow me to build the apk:

```
Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined.
Faceted Project Problem
```

I checked the project and its dependencies for problems in the Java Build Path with no luck. They don't reference Apache Tomcat in any part.

I've found that for Java projects this kind of error can be fixed by going to the Project Facets menu on the project's settings.

Is there a way to access this menu from an Android project?

If not, is there another way to fix this?

Thank you